# Generic method for database calls

Tags: php, object-oriented, postgresql, delegates

## Background

Breaking from MVC, I've implemented the following architecture:

```
POST/GET ➤ PHP ➤ Database Calls ➤ XML ➤ XSLT ➤ HTML
```

All database interactions are relegated to the `call` method in the `Database` class, without exception. This adheres to the DRY principle. This design allows the following, which is a critical application feature:

```
... ➤ XML ➤ XSLT ➤ LaTeX ➤ PDF
```

The same code that retrieves data to render as an interactive web page is exactly the same code *and* XML used to render a PDF. Eventually additional output formats will be required:

```
... ➤ XML ➤ XSLT ➤ XML
... ➤ XML ➤ XSLT ➤ ASCII Text
```

Using this architecture, the same database functions can be used to generate completely different output formats.

## Common Code

The code that makes database calls can do so in one of three ways:

```
$this->call( "database_function", "c1, c2, c3", $v1, $v2, $v3 );
$this->call( "database_function", "c1, c2, c3" ) );
$this->call( "database_procedure" ) );
```

The parameters are variable arguments.

## Database Class

My questions pertain to the database class itself:

```
<?php
use PDO;
use PDOException;

/**
 * Used for interacting with the database. Usage:
 * <pre>
 * $db = Database::get();
 * $db->call( ... );
 * </pre>
 */
class Database extends Obj {
  private static $instance;
  private $dataStore;

  /**
   * Sets the connection that this class uses for database transactions.
   */
  public function __construct() {
    global $dbhost;
    global $dbname;
    global $dbuser;
    global $dbpass;

    try {
      $this->setDataStore(
        new PDO( "pgsql:dbname=$dbname;host=$dbhost", $dbuser, $dbpass ) );
    }
    catch( PDOException $ex ) {
      $this->log( $ex->getMessage() );
    }
  }

  /**
   * Returns the singleton database instance.
   */
  public function get() {
    if( self::$instance === null ) {
      self::$instance = new Database();
    }

    return self::$instance;
  }

  /**
   * Call a database function and return the results. If there are
   * multiple columns to return, then the value for $params must contain
   * a comma; otherwise, without a comma, the value for $params is used
   * as the return column name. For example:
   *
   *- SELECT $params FROM $proc( ?, ? ); -- with comma
   *- SELECT $proc( ?, ? ) AS $params; -- without comma
   *- SELECT $proc( ?, ? ); -- empty
   *
   * @param $proc Name of the function or stored procedure to call.
   * @param $params Name of parameters to use as return columns.
   */
  public function call( $proc, $params = "" ) {
    $args = array();
    $count = 0;
    $placeholders = "";

    // Key is zero-based (e.g., $proc = 0, $params = 1).
    foreach( func_get_args() as $key => $parameter ) {
      // Skip the $proc and $params arguments to this method.
      if( $key < 2 ) continue;

      $count++;
      $placeholders = empty( $placeholders ) ? "?" : "$placeholders,?";
      array_push( $args, $parameter );
    }

    $sql = "";

    if( empty( $params ) ) {
      // If there are no parameters, then just make a call.
      $sql = "SELECT $proc( $placeholders )";
    }
    else if( strpos( $params, "," ) !== false ) {
      // If there is a comma, select the column names.
      $sql = "SELECT $params FROM $proc( $placeholders )";
    }
    else {
      // Otherwise, select the result into the given column name.
      $sql = "SELECT $proc( $placeholders ) AS $params";
    }

    $statement = $this->getDataStore()->prepare( $sql );

    //$this->log( "SQL: $sql" );

    for( $i = 1; $i <= $count; $i++ ) {
      //$this->log( "Bind " . $i . " to " . $args[$i - 1] );
      $statement->bindParam( $i, $args[$i - 1] );
    }

    $statement->execute();
    $result = $statement->fetchAll();
    $this->decodeArray( $result );

    return $result;
  }

  /**
   * Converts an array of numbers into an array suitable for usage with
   * PostgreSQL.
   *
   * @param $array An array of integers.
   */
  public function arrayToString( $array ) {
    return "{" . implode( ",", $array ) . "}";
  }

  /**
   * Recursive method to decode a UTF8-encoded array.
   *
   * @param $array - The array to decode.
   * @param $key - Name of the function to call.
   */
  private function decodeArray( &$array ) {
    if( is_array( $array ) ) {
      array_map( array( $this, "decodeArray" ), $array );
    }
    else {
      $array = utf8_decode( $array );
    }
  }

  private function getDataStore() {
    return $this->dataStore;
  }

  private function setDataStore( $dataStore ) {
    $this->dataStore = $dataStore;
  }
}
?>
```

A `BaseController` class abstracts the persistence layer from subclasses as follows:

```
  protected function call() {
    $db = Database::get();
    return call_user_func_array( array( $db, "call" ), func_get_args() );
  }
```

Thus subclasses can call `$this->call(...)` without knowing about the database.

## Example Usage #1

The database functionality is used, for example as an AJAX request, as follows:

```
class AjaxPhotographCategory extends Ajax {
  function __construct() {
    parent::__construct();
  }

  public function handleAjaxRequest() {
    return $this->json( $this->call(
      "get_photograph_category_list", "id, label, description" ) );
  }
}
?>
```

## Example Usage #2

Here is another example usage:

```
  private function exists( $cookie_value ) {
    $result = $this->call( "is_existing_cookie", "existing", $cookie_value );

    return isset( $result[0] ) ? $result[0]["existing"] > 0 : false;
  }
```

The return line could be abstracted and simplified, but that's not an important detail.

## Example Usage #3

The code to generate an XML document resembles (where `"x"` is the column name to hold XML content):

```
  private function getXml() {
    $result = $this->call( "generate_account_xml", "x", $this->getId() );

    return isset( $result[0] ) ? $result[0]["x"] : $this->getErrorXml( "account" );
  }
```

## Example Usage #4

Information is added to the database as follows:

```
  private function authenticate() {
    $this->call( "authentication_upsert", "",
      $this->getCookieToken(),
      $this->getBrowserPlatform(),
      $this->getBrowserName(),
      $this->getBrowserVersion(),
      $this->getIp()
    );
  }
```

Since this calls a stored procedure, the return value can be discarded. As `call` requires two values (database routine name and return column name) to precede the arguments passed into the database routine, the second parameter must be filled with *something* (hence `""`).

This could be abstracted by splitting `call` into `callProc` and `callFunc`, so I'd consider the extraneous empty string parameter to be a minor detail.

## Questions

My questions are:

- What performance impacts or security issues may be encountered?
- What improvements could be made to alleviate those issues?
- How could the implementation be changed to ease maintenance?

Comment: Do I get this right that you are trying to move most of your logic to stored procedures?

Comment: All persistence logic is in stored procedures already. The entire PHP code base has only three `SELECT` statements (shown). There are no `INSERT`, `UPDATE`, or `DELETE` statements in the code base and my plan is to keep it that way. My concern is around the performance and security impacts of the Database class.

Comment: Although I'm getting OT here. Isn't this a maintenance and testing nightmare? I'm really interested in some sample procedures here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's my sniff at the first things I saw for the code (not the implementation).

```
public function __construct() {
    ...
    try {
      $this->setDataStore(
        new PDO( "pgsql:dbname=$dbname;host=$dbhost", $dbuser, $dbpass ) );
    }
    ...
```

Above, a class is instantiating a class, and not injecting dependencies.

Pass arguments to the constructor with the dependencies that a class requires:

```
public function __construct(PDO $pdo) {
    $this->dataStore = $pdo;
}
```

In addition, use the magic `__get()` and `__set()` methods instead of explicitly declared accessors to vastly improve readability and maintenance ease. [Here's the documentation](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.overloading.php), remember it, and learn to love it.

```
public function __get(string $name) {
    // Logic/cases to check name for correct stores here.
}
```

Comment: Exposing the PDO class through the constructor would mean that any class wanting to use the Database class would need to know about PDO, which would defeat the purpose of a Database singleton.

Comment: The `__get` and `__set` methods look interesting. If the `__get` method can be made `private`, that pattern will be quite handy.

Comment: @DaveJarvis in PHP, magic methods must be public. You can control access inside that function, though, and keep all attributes private/protected

Comment: The magic methods are [3 times slower](http://www.garfieldtech.com/blog/magic-benchmarks). Although you should not start a premature optimization, you should be aware of this fact.

Comment: Maybe you can replace your global variables by some kind of configuration object.

Comment: @mnhg it's a trade-off for maintenance value; getters/setters for every single value (in my experience) turned into maintenance hell.

Comment: The global variables are generated from a database. All constants are in a table, which gets exported as XML. The XML is then transformed into PHP, JavaScript, or XSLT as required. ;-)