# Optimize PHP and MySQL with PDO

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I am updating some old reports that are using `mysql_` statements and trying to use the MySQL PDO stuff.  I was told that PDO is far better since I was running into runtime issues with some of my reports.  My old report took 91 seconds to run, and my PDO version takes 106 seconds.  While 15 seconds may not seem like a big deal, this report is dealing with 1 week's worth of data, and other reports deal with a month up to a year.  Additionally, my `$cart_total` doesn't seem to work in the PDO version.

I would appreciate any help optimizing my queries (though I think they are pretty solid), and my PHP/PDO code.

```
<?php
    $start_time = time();
    require_once('db_configuration.php');

    $db = new PDO('mysql:host=' . $db_host . ';dbname=' . $db_name . ';charset=utf8', $db_username, $db_password, array(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES => false, 
                                                                                                PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION));

    $key_query_raw = "SELECT configuration_key, configuration_value FROM configuration WHERE configuration_group_id = 6501 AND configuration_key IN('RCS_BASE_DAYS', 'RCS_EMAIL_TTL', 'RCS_SKIP_DAYS') ORDER BY configuration_key ASC;";
    try { $key_query = $db->query($key_query_raw); }
        catch(PDOException $ex) { echo "An Error occured! <br><br>" . $ex; }

    while($key = $key_query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) 
    {
        if ($key['configuration_key'] == 'RCS_BASE_DAYS') { $base_days = $key['configuration_value']; }
        elseif ($key['configuration_key'] == 'RCS_EMAIL_TTL') { $ttl_days = $key['configuration_value']; }
        elseif ($key['configuration_key'] == 'RCS_SKIP_DAYS') { $skip_days = $key['configuration_value']; }
    }

    $key_query->closeCursor();

    $skip_date =  date('Ymd',strtotime('-'.$skip_days.' day',time()));
    $base_date =  date('Ymd',strtotime('-'.$base_days.' day',time()));
    $ttl_date =  date('Ymd',strtotime('-'.$ttl_days.' day',time()));
?>
<html>
    <style type="text/css">
        .row {
            padding-left:5px;
            padding-right:5px;
            border-style:solid;
            border-color:black;
            border-width:1px;
            border-width:0 0 1 0;
        }

        .header {
            background-color:#C8C8C8;
            text-align:left;
            font-weight:bold;
            padding-left:5px;
            padding-right:5px;
            border-style:solid;
            border-color:black;
            border-width:0 0 3 0;
        }
    </style>

    <head>
        <title>Recover Cart Sales Test</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="reports.css" />
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    </head>

    <body>
        <table style="border-collapse:collapse;" width=100%>
            <tr>
                <td class="header">Contacted</td>
                <td class="header">Date</td>
                <td class="header">Customer Name</td>
                <td class="header" colspan=2>Email</td>
                <td class="header">Phone</td>
                <td class="header">&nbsp;</td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td class="header">&nbsp;</td>
                <td class="header">Item</td>
                <td class="header" colspan=2>Description</td>
                <td class="header" width=20>Qty</td>
                <td class="header" width=20>Price</td>
                <td class="header" width=20>Total</td>
            </tr>

<?


    $customer_query_raw = "SELECT DISTINCT cb.customers_id, cb.customers_basket_date_added, c.customers_firstname, c.customers_lastname, c.customers_email_address, c.customers_telephone, sc.datemodified AS last_contacted
                             FROM customers_basket cb
                             INNER JOIN customers c ON c.customers_id = cb.customers_id
                             LEFT JOIN scart sc ON cb.customers_id = sc.customers_id
                             WHERE cb.customers_basket_date_added < " . $skip_date . " 
                                AND cb.customers_basket_date_added > " . $base_date . " 
                                AND cb.customers_id NOT IN (SELECT sc.customers_id FROM scart sc WHERE sc.datemodified > " . $ttl_date . ")
                             ORDER BY cb.customers_basket_date_added DESC;";

    try { $customer_query = $db->query($customer_query_raw); }
        catch(PDOException $ex) { echo "An Error occured! <br><br>" . $ex; }

    $customer_row_count = $customer_query->rowCount();

    while($customer = $customer_query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) 
    {
        $product_query_raw = "SELECT cb.customers_id, cb.products_id, p.products_model, pd.products_name, cb.customers_basket_quantity, p.products_price, (p.products_price * cb.customers_basket_quantity) AS product_total
                                FROM customers_basket cb, products p, products_description pd
                                WHERE cb.customers_id = " . $customer['customers_id'] . " 
                                    AND cb.products_id = pd.products_id
                                    AND p.products_id = pd.products_id";
        try { $product_query = $db->query($product_query_raw); }
        catch(PDOException $ex) { echo "An Error occured! <br><br>" . $ex; }

        $cart_total_query_raw = "SELECT SUM( p.products_price * cb.customers_basket_quantity ) AS cart_total
                                    FROM customers_basket cb, products p
                                    WHERE cb.customers_id = " . $customer['customers_id'] . " 
                                    AND cb.products_id = p.products_id;";
        try { $cart_total_query = $db->query($cart_total_query_raw); }
        catch(PDOException $ex) { echo "An Error occured! <br><br>" . $ex; }

        $result = $cart_total_query->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
        $cart_total = $result['cart_total'];
        $cart_total_query->closeCursor();

        $last_contacted = ($customer['last_contacted'] < $ttl_date || $customer['last_contacted'] == NULL) ? 'Uncontacted' : date('Y-m-d', strtotime($customer['last_contacted']));
?>
        <tr>
            <td class="row"><?= $last_contacted; ?></td>
            <td class="row"><?= date('Y-m-d', strtotime($customer['customers_basket_date_added'])); ?></td>
            <td class="row"><?= $customer['customers_firstname'] . ' ' . $customer['customers_lastname']; ?></td>
            <td class="row" colspan=2><?= $customer['customers_email_address']; ?></td>
            <td class="row"><?= $customer['customers_telephone']; ?></td>
            <td class="row">&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>       
<?
        while($product = $product_query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
        {
?>
            <tr>
                <td>&nbsp;</td>
                <td class="row"><?= $product['products_model']; ?></td>
                <td class="row" colspan=2><?= $product['products_name']; ?></td>
                <td class="row" width=20><?= $product['customers_basket_quantity']; ?>x </td>
                <td class="row" width=20><?= $product['products_price']; ?></td>
                <td class="row" width=20><?= $product['product_total']; ?></td>
            </tr>
<?
        }
?>
            <tr>
                <td colspan=7 style="font-weight:bold; text-align:right;">Cart Total: <?= $cart_total; ?></td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td>&nbsp;</td>
            </tr>

<?
            $product_query->closeCursor();
    } // End While

    $customer_query->closeCursor(); 
    $db = NULL;
?>
        </table>
        <br><br>
<?
    $end_time = time();

    echo "Number of Records: " . $customer_row_count . "<br>";
    echo "Start: " . $start_time . "<br>";
    echo "End: " . $end_time . "<br>";
    echo "Time Elapsed: " . ($end_time - $start_time);
?>  
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Fixed my non-working $cart_total by using fetch vs fetchALL (not sure why I had fetchAll).

Comment: if speed is what you're after, forget about `PDO`, and go for `mysqli_*`. It's the fastest of the two. And don't forget the classic DNS bottleneck, in case you're passing the host-name as a string, and not IP... And don't, for the love of God do this: `catch(PDOException $ex) { echo "An Error occured! <br><br>" . $ex; }`. Not only is `$ex` an object, you're not stopping the rest of the script, it'll still continue to run as though the error _never_ occurred. That's just plain wrong

Comment: I also noticed you're using the short-tag quite a few times. Now this is probably down to the code being legacy and all that, but when mixing PHP in with markup the `<?` tag isn't a great idea. It never is, really, because `<?xml`<--: having short-tags enabled, enables PHP parsing on what, essentially, is XML

Comment: @Elias  Thank you for your comments, they were very useful.  What would be a better approach for the error?  For now, I want it to print the error on-screen for debugging.  Once complete, it will write to a logfile (which I know how to do).  I should probably use $ex->getMessage() vs just $ex though...

Comment: I'd like to refer this question to my answer [here](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/26581/mysql-vs-pdo-execution-time/26818#26818). Basically, PDO has some trouble resolving a hostname, so use the IP address of the server instead of 'localhost' or 'mydb.com', etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I were you, I would try to add some sort of index to your MySQL database for this fields:

```
cb.customers_basket_date_added
cb.customers_id
```

when this is done I would make changes your SQL, something similar to this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
    cb.customers_id, 
    cb.customers_basket_date_added, 
    c.customers_firstname, 
    c.customers_lastname, 
    c.customers_email_address, 
    c.customers_telephone, 
    sc.datemodified AS last_contacted
FROM 
    customers_basket cb 
    INNER JOIN customers c ON c.customers_id = cb.customers_id
    LEFT JOIN scart sc ON cb.customers_id = sc.customers_id
WHERE 
    ( cb.customers_basket_date_added BETWEEN '{start-date}' AND '{end-date}' ) AND
    NOT EXISTS (
                SELECT  
                    sc.customers_id 
                FROM 
                    scart sc 
                WHERE
                    sc.datemodified > '{date-modified}' AND
                    sc.{customerId-field} = cb.customers_id )
                ORDER BY 
                    cb.customers_basket_date_added DESC
```

I changed your `NOT IN` function to `NOT EXISTS`, and changed a lot more.

Why are you using distinct and not group by function?

when this SQL performs fast we can go to next step, the SQL inside your loop.

Is it posible to make a SQL dump so that I can download it and help you out more?

I think you have a big mistake in your 3rd block of SQL, maybe it can be done with only 1 SQL select and not 1 select * 2 select each loop run, this mean if you got 90 rows out you make 181 selects, I am sure that you can do it with less select statements being run against the SQL Server.

Comment: Thank you for your response, it was very useful.  While I think I could ultimately combine the 'customer' query and the 'product' query, I could not figure out how to combine the 'cart total' query.  Which is faster, performing a query that would return the 1 record with the SUM, or to add the products as I loop through them via PHP $cart_total =+ $cart_total + $product['product_total']